# Upgrading application from .net 2.0 to .net 4.7

Tags: visual-studio, iis, asp.net-web-api, upgrade, .net-4.7.2

I am solution architect. I need to upgrade my application from .net 2.0 to .net 4.7
What will be the roadmap for that there is no change code or architecture of application
I have Windows server 10 ready it comes with .net 4.5 or higher.
What should I do with IIS ?
Does that needs to be changed to ?
What are the other steps to follow?
Thank you
Suji

Comment: There is nothing called "Windows server 10", so edit the question to tell clearly what you are targeting. You cannot migrate to .NET Framework 4.x without code change, and possibly even architectural change can be required. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes covers most typical ones, but more should be expected. Upgrade, let it break, and then you can search for solutions and learn from people who migrated decades ago.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention its windows server 2019 not windows server 10